# How to parse this String to timestamp timezone issue

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat

How to parse this String to timestamp timezone issue ?

```
String timestamp = "29-JAN-2014 01:00:00.000 PM EUROPE/PARIS";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS aa ZZZ");

Date dateFormatted = null; 

        try {
            dateFormatted = df.parse(timestamp);
        } catch (ParseException execption) {
            execption.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This code seem to be fine. What problem do you have?

Comment: No it is throwing the error "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "29-JAN-2014 01:00:00.000 PM EUROPE/PARIS""

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java simple date format british time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965681/java-simple-date-format-british-time)

Comment: @OIS context is bit different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris")
String timestamp = "29-JAN-2014 01:00:00.000 PM";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS aa");
df.setTimeZone(tz)

try {
    dateFormatted = df.parse(timestamp);
} catch (ParseException execption) {
    execption.printStackTrace();
}
```

But you have to split the timezone from the timestamp

Comment: String operations :(

Comment: Your answer works. Nothing better solution is available. Thank you.